# Throwing an error from a promises catch block fails the test for it being handled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm throwing an error from a `$httpBackend` response to a function and then logging and rethrowing in the catch part of an AngularJS promise chain:

```
function doAThingThatMustBeLogged(param) {
    return ExternalService.thingToLogFunction(param).then(response =>{
        MyLogger.Log('All is well');
    }).catch(error => {
        MyLogger.Log('Oh no.');
        throw new Error(error);
    })
}

it('should log doAThingThatMustBeLogged regardless of any errors thrown', () =>{
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('https://external-service.com/api/thing/to/log').respond(500);
    spyOn(MyLogger, 'Log');
    doAThingThatMustBeLogged(1)
    try {
        $httpBackend.flush();
    } catch (error) {
        // swallow error
    }
    expect(MyLogger.Log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Oh no.');
})
```

Now I am only rethrowing the error as I don't want to swallow it in the non-test code, because the code that calls `doAThingThatMustBeLogged` can handle it better higher up. However what this means is that I now need to wrap `$httpBackend.flush` in my test in a try/catch block which then implies an error is thrown.

That implication - that this function throws errors - is not what I want the test to do. I just want to isolate the logging code and test that is called satisfactorially.

Is there a way to run the test above, without having to try // catch around the flush?

Comment: Why are you using `try/catch` on `$httpBackend.flush()` when the function that is actually throwing an error, per your example code, is `doAThingThatMustBeLogged()`?

Comment: @Herohtar it's a side effect of AngularJS relying on a digest cycle. When you `flush()` it actually triggers the cycle and fires the `respond` from the `expectPOST`, then the error ends up coming 'from' the `flush`. One of the many weird things that make me not like this pattern.